# Do I need to keep my gpu control panel active?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

I've been using onboard graphics for the longest time.
But I finally got a gpu. A low end one but still better than onboard.
But when I put the gpu in, it installed nvidia geforce experience.
And I'm just wondering, do I need to keep that running all the time?
Can I disable it?
Should I disable it?
I'm sure it isn't really a problem. I just like having the quickest boot time possible.

Comment: geforce experience is required if you want to stream or auto optimize your games according to specs of your system. other than it is not necessary to keep it running.

Answer (score 0):

The control panel does not need to be running for the drivers to work under normal conditions, however, there are some optimization functions that need the panel to be running in the background to detect if a compatible programme is running so it can change settings.